# Cron Job To Disable Product Magento 1.7 CE

Tags: magento-1.7

How do I set up a cron job in magento step by step. If I have a attribute that has a set date, i want the cron job to disable the product if the day has past...

Comment: Did you found solution ?

Answer (score 4):

1) Create a custom Module, there's many guides to this out there - or use a Module Creator to get your started.

2) Added Cron job setup to your modules config

**config.xml**

```
...
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <mymodule_disable>
                <schedule>
                    <!-- every 10 min -->
                    <cron_expr>*/10 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>mymodule/Scheduler::disable</model>
                </run>
            </mymodule_disable>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>

</config>
```

Now Create an class to handle the task for you (modulename/Model/Scheduler.php)

**Scheduler.php**

```
<?php
class Mymodule_Model_Scheduler
{
    /**
     * Disable prodcuts for us
     */
    public static function disable()
    {
         // This will be run every 10 minutes, we want to get applicable products
         // you will need to customize the filter for what you need, subtracting
         // or adding date values etc.. you get the idea :)
         $date = Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate(); // add/subtract etc
         $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
         $collection->addfieldtofilter('custom_date_attr', array(
             array('to' => $date),
             //array('gteq' => $date)
         ));
         foreach($collection as $product) {
             $product->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
             $product->save();
         }
    }
}
```

Now you need to setup a cron job to run Magentos Scheduler, example:

```
*/10 * * * *  php -f /path/to/magento/cron.php
```