# Simple products to be shown between dates in a category in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

Well I'm kind of new with magento, and at work they ask me to do a group of products that they will be put in discount, so I created a category sales where I can link the products and put them in sale, so this is working perfectly, but the ask me to put dates in the products so the web master can put dates where the products will be shown between dates, so now I have no idea how to do this. I really hope you guys can help me

thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an extension with a cron job and also attribute/attributes for that.

This topic will help you to get started:

[Cron Job To Disable Product Magento 1.7 CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293528/cron-job-to-disable-product-magento-1-7-ce)

There is also extension that should work in your installation (I assume you have Magento 1.5):

[Ecomdev Sheduled Products](http://shop.ecomdev.org/scheduled-products.html)